Switch mobile site to desktop site using desktop browser
Mobile browser has a desktop site option. It will switch mobile site to desktop site. It works when there is a "m" at the start of the URL. But desktop browser doesn't have a desktop site option. And some site won't automatically redirect to desktop site when I am using desktop browser.
So I want to know how to manually switch a mobile site to desktop site when it didn't automatically redirect. I have tested such a site in mobile browser and click on desktop site option. It works. So I just need the same option in desktop browser.

Remove the "m." at the start of the URL?

What sort of Google searches are returning mobile site results? Is it perhaps syncing your browsing history and you're viewing the mobile site versions you've opened on mobile? I think you're possibly observing a problem that you are inadvertently causing yourself.

Every result on that page except the first is a non-mobile version. The site host has decided to push their mobile version, for some reason.  You might be able to use something like a browser script tool like TamperMonkey to accomplish what you want.

@music2myear Sometimes I search images, posts or news. Many results are mobile. I think this is because mobile devices and hence mobile sites are become popular. So Google put in at the top. If I search simply facebook, the result might be desktop site. But If I search something detail in facebook. Sometimes more results are mobile, sometimes not.

Please find an example that is safe for work.

@Ramhound I removed it.

Your desktop browser is already a desktop browser. Unlike a mobile browser, it does not need to impersonate a desktop browser, which is what this option does.

@DanielB No. By click the option I can manually switch to desktop site. But desktop browser doesn't have that option. If the site didn't automatically redirect to desktop version when I am using desktop browser. How can I do?


On a desktop the browser by default act as desktop.
On Firefox e.g. you can switch with with CTRL+SHIFT+M between Mobile and desktop identifications.
Some sites are designed to be responsive (A responsive web design will automatically adjust for different screen sizes and viewports). It means that if the windows of your desktop browser is too little the site may think that you are using a mobile phone...
"m." at the start of the URL may force the site to give you a mobile layout.


@rint Some sites are using browser window width to determine whether to show a mobile or desktop browser - is the browser window maximized when this occurs?

@JW0914 Yep, maximized. Those websites are traditional. They don't have responsive web design.

I found a chrome extension called Mobile View Switcher can do what I asked. It can switch between mobile site and desktop site, unlike F12 Developer Tools. DevTools can only switch from desktop site to mobile site.
Both Mobile View Switcher and desktop site option in mobile browser can work when there is a "m" at the start of the URL.

On a desktop the browser by default acts using the desktop design mode. You do not need to do anything. On a mobile phone you can select it with a switch in the options.
On Firefox (or Chrome) e.g., you can toggle with CTRL+SHIFT+M between Mobile and Desktop Responsive Design Mode. It will allow you to select the horizontal and vertical layout of your emulated phone, the screen definition in pixels and one from a few hardware models. The key combination may depend on the browser/system/language.
Some sites are designed to be responsive. A responsive web design will automatically adjust for different screen sizes and viewports. It means that if the windows of your desktop browser is too little the site (or your browser) may think that you are using a mobile phone/tablet and change its layout.
Note that the "m." at the start of the URL may force the site/browser to give you a mobile layout (usually is the site itself to provide a different version for mobile).

The behavior of it is the same as F12 Developer Tools. I describe in my answer. It doesn't work. Mobile View Switcher and desktop site option in mobile browser can switch a URL which has "m" at the start to desktop URL.

It is the behavior by default. CTRL+SHIFT+M is the way to toggle between mobile/desktop layout. There is no need to install any extension when there is something built-in. Neither to change options, nor to use Developer Tools as a whole. The key combination may depend on the browser/system/language. In general, the questions and answers on this site are not limited to the benefit of the OP (you in this case). We try to give an answer that can solve the problem for other people/situations too. What you ask is not accurate/true. Situations that could lead to unexpected behavior are shown.
